# How to access values from keys from Local Storage in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I want to access the values from some keys in my **Local Storage** in the most easiest way with **AngularJs**.
In **Resources** --> **Local Storage** I have:

```
Key:myKey
Value:{ "layouts":[ other_things ],"states":{ other_things  },"storageHash":"fs4df4d51"}
```

I tried:

```
console.log($window.localStorage.key(0).valueOf('layouts'));
  //or
console.log($window.localStorage.getItem('myKey'));
```

**RESULT**

> myKey

Comment: Hello Vlad , I suggest using localStorageService module written for browser's localstorage , it helps a lot.Check out the url https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Comment: @katmanco yes, thank you, I have seen that module. I want to test this out first for something else, and if it succeed, I will install the module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
$window.localStorage['myKey']
```

If the data is of stringified(read: JSON.stringify) then:

```
angular.fromJson($window.localStorage['myKey']);
```

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage stores values in strings, not objects. You will need to serialize your object before assigning it and deserialize it when fetching.

```
var myObject= { "layouts":[ other_things ],"states":{ other_things  },"storageHash":"fs4df4d51"};

// Stringify JSON object before storing
localStorage.setItem('myKey', JSON.stringify(myObject));

// Retrieve the object
var myRetrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('testObject'));
```

Answer (score 0):

From local storage you get JSON data, so you need to parse it to JS object, 
JSON.parse($window.localStorage.myKey).layouts